# How to resolve error "Must use import to load ES Module" with karma

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

Our project has `"type": "module"` in the `package.json` file and the test runner is invoked using `karma start ./src/tests/config/karma.conf.main.js` but it reports the following error when ran:

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/me/git/project/src/tests/config/karma.conf.main.js

The contents of the `karma.conf.main.js` is a minimal as it can possibly be:

```js
import './karma.conf.common';
```

Comment: What is your node version?

Comment: @Schwarz54 v14.15.1 and karma v6.3.4 modules are loading fine in the main sources.

Comment: @LeaHayes, Have you found a solution for this?